# Regularize Non-existent path in C on Linux

Tags: c, validation, path

I am writing a utility function for a c program which creates directories, but will also create any intermediate directories which do not exist. I have that code working, but I wanted to turn my attention to improve user input formatting. Namely, I want to regularize the input path before I process it, especially to remove `//` which will break my current implementation.

I am aware of `realpath(3)`, but my main issue is that it will fail if any of the directories on the path do not already exist. The command line function `realpath(1)` has the `-m` option, which seems to do what I want, but I don't want to invoke a shell if I can avoid it (Otherwise I could do `mkdir -p` and be done with it). Gnu `findutils/canonicalize.h` has `canonicalize_filename_mode`, but I don't know how to reference that short of copying the source directly (not out of the question). Thoughts, suggestions?

I am tied to my development environment `gcc 4.7.7`and `rhel 6.6`.

Below is my current implementation.

```
static int do_mkdir(const char *path, mode_t mode) {
    struct stat     st;
    int             status = 0;

    if ( stat(path, &st) != 0 ) {

       errno = 0;

        if (mkdir(path, mode) != 0 && errno != EEXIST)
            status = -1;

    } else if ( !S_ISDIR(st.st_mode) ) {
        errno = ENOTDIR;
        status = -1;
    }

    return(status);
}

int mkpath(const char *path, mode_t mode) {

    char *pp;
    char *sp;
    int   status;

    char copypath[PATH_MAX+1];
    copypath = realpath(path, copypath);

    status = 0;
    pp = copypath;

    if(copypath == NULL)
        status = -1;

    while ( status == 0 && (sp = strchr(pp, '/')) != 0 ) {

        if (sp != pp) {

            *sp = '\0';
            status = do_mkdir(copypath, mode);
            *sp = '/';

        }

        pp = sp + 1;

    }

    if ( status == 0 )
        status = do_mkdir(path, mode);

    return (status);

}
```

Comment: Both findutils and coreutils (which is where `realpath(3)` comes from) use gnulib (https://www.gnu.org/software/gnulib/). This is where `canonicalize_filename_mode()` comes from. I'm not aware of any handy plain POSIX functions for canonicalizing pathnames with missing components, so short of using gnulib or some other library which happens to provide similar functionality (or rolling your own), you may be out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

It might not fully answer your issue but here is an alternative:

You could process the `path` string with `strtok`, setting `delim` argument to `'/'`.
By doing so, `strtok` will return you intermediate directory names (null-terminated: you can get rid off the `\0` tweak) and it will gracefully ignore `//`.
You can then add your "sanitize" checks (look for invalid characters, path name is too long, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround that I believe covers all cases. What I did, was to move the call to `realpath` into the `do_mkdir` function so that way it will only have at most one non-existent element, replacing it with a strdup in the `mkpath` function. I can't think of a situation where performing the canonicalization on a partial path will break anything either.